# Dynamically created grid in PHP/CSS looks wrong only in Android Firefox browser?

Tags: php, android, html, css, firefox

I am working on a new adoptable dog listing for my rescue's website. I created a listings page that pulls pictures and information from a third party API, and then lists them:

http://dallaspetsalive.org/new-adoptables/

The goal is, in a normal browser, the divs with the images and info are floated to either the left or the right, making a two column list, but as the screen gets smaller it goes down to one column.

This works in every browser I've tried except Firefox on my Android. I am puzzled as to why it would be different there. It's like the divs are overlapping. Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy2F3.png

Here is the PHP code.

```
                foreach($dogsList as $dog) {
                    $num = $num + 1;
                    if($left) {
                        echo "<div id=\"pet-search-left\">";
                        $left = 0;
                    } else {
                        echo "<div id=\"pet-search-right\">";
                        $left = 1;
                    }

                    echo "<a href=\"dog-profile?id=";
                    echo $dog['animalID'];
                    echo "\" style=\"text-decoration: underline; color: #006bb7;\">";
                    echo "<img src=\"";
                    echo $dog['animalThumbnailUrl'];
                    echo "\" style=\"float: left; margin-right: 10px;\" /><h3>";
                    echo $dog['animalName'];
                    echo "</h3></a>";
                    echo $dog['animalGeneralAge'];
                    echo " ";
                    echo $dog['animalSex'];
                    echo "<br />";
                    echo $dog['animalGeneralSizePotential'];
                    echo "<br />";
                    echo $dog['animalBreed'];
                    echo "</div>";
                }
```

Here is the relevant CSS for normal size:

```
#pet-search-left { width: 270px; float: left; height: 200px; padding: 3px;}
#pet-search-right { width: 270px; float: right; height: 200px; padding: 3px;}
```

Smaller sizes:

```
#pet-search-left { width: 100%; height: 200px;}
#pet-search-right { width: 100%; height: 200px;}
```

What is going on?

Edit: It's also wrong on Android Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by adding a new line (literally an enter) after the div.

So literally

```
echo "</div>
";
```

instead of

```
echo "</div>";
```

No idea why that changed it.